# Why can't I adjust my button/label size when using "ttk."?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have to place a "ttk." behind every labels and buttons that I make because otherwise the text wouldn't display on the labels and buttons.

```
myButton = Button(root,text="test",padx=200,pady=20).pack()
```

This would just display a white rectangular with no text until I clicked it which temporary changes to blue and displays the text that was assigned to it in the code.

My main problem is that I'm not able to change the padx/pady/columnspan when I have the "ttk." behind my labels and buttons

```
myButton = ttk.Button(root,text="test",padx=200,pady=20).pack()
```

This code results in this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-padx"
```

I am using MacOs if anyone's wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because ttk uses padding as one keyword. Your example would be now:

```
myButton = ttk.Button(root,text="test",padding="200 30 200 30").pack()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!, it works now. Just one more thing, how do  I use the columnspan command in the .grid argument so that 1 button expands to the size of 2 columns?

Comment: well, first you would have to switch to using the grid geometry manager and not pack. then you set the argument in there to `columnspan=2`. Code for button: `myButton = ttk.Button(root,text="test",padding="200 30 200 30").grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2)` It doesn't look like it spans two columns, but it does, you just need to have another element that takes up the columns and rows adjacent to it.

Comment: also, you might notice that the button doesn't resize. add `sticky='nsew'` in the grid arguments to define how it would stick if the window resizes. then add `root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)` and `root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)` in previous lines to say that it _should_ resize. Just wanted to say that :]

Comment: Thank you. It is just what I envisioned in the first place.

Comment: Just a note: you should call `.pack()` _after_ creating the button. Assigning `myButton` to `ttk.Button(root,text="test",padding="200 30 200 30").pack()` will assign it to `None`, because that's what `.pack()` returns. Use `myButton = ttk.Button(root,text="test",padding="200 30 200 30")` and _then_ `myButton.pack()`.